# Where get data/api for get food recipe and/or nutrition facts?

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm thinking in build a iPhone app for get recipes. So, I'm looking for resources where I can get the data of that recipes in a way I can use in my app, store locally and/or query.

I'm interested in get nutrition facts, photos, etc... I understand that maybe I need to collect the data from several sources (like flickr photos?), but any starting point will be very useful.

Comment: This isn't exactly a programming question. Maybe the FDA or some agency has this info online somewhere?

Comment: disagree. People frequently ask where to find api's on stack overflow

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can download the USDA database[1] here[2]. No photos, but lots of interesting data.

1. http://www.nal.usda.gov/fnic/foodcomp/search/
2. http://www.ars.usda.gov/Services/docs.htm?docid=18879

Comment: New revision (SR23): http://www.ars.usda.gov/Services/docs.htm?docid=20959

Answer (score 9):

The **[FatSecret Platform](http://platform.fatsecret.com/)** might be helpful for nutrition facts. They have RESTful and JavaScript APIs that are free if you link to their site.

Comment: Can you give me a hint how to start using this API? I want to use it in my application, but have not clue how to begin dealing with it. what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

[Freebase](http://www.freebase.com/) contains useful information about all sorts of things, I'm sure there is probably information aplenty about nutritional value of food stuffs. It is probably also helpful that it is easily accessible programmatically through their API.

Comment: I'm just using it right now to create a calorie / nutrient calculator! Good stuff.

Comment: Unfortunately "The Freebase API will be retired on June 30, 2015" :(

Answer (score -1):

The [Punchfork Recipe API](http://punchfork.com/api) provides recipe data from food blogs and mainstream recipe sites, along with thumbnail images.

Comment: Please can you ensure that you disclose your affiliation with this site and its API in both your posts and profile. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion  Thanks.

Comment: Punchfork was sold to Pinterest Jan 2013.